# Horizontal line through text (and screen) on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to reproduce an effect I saw the other day on another site. There's a heading and when you hover over it a horizontal line appears through the text and over the screen. I'm almost finished, however, when I hover over the place where the line is hidden it appears (which it shouldn't).

I have experimented with the position and width of the divs with no success (I can't change the width of the divs without changing the width of the line).

HTML:

```
<div id="index_wrapper">
    <p class="heading">THIS IS A TEST</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#index_wrapper {
    margin-top: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
}
.heading { 
    line-height:0.1em;
} 
.heading.active { 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".heading").hover(function(){
        $(".heading").toggleClass("active");
    });
});
```

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/5bhgsxv2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add one span to capture hover event only on the text

```
<div id="index_wrapper">
     <p class="heading"><span>THIS IS A TEST</span></p>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".heading span").hover(function(){
    $(".heading").toggleClass("active");
  });
});
```

or if the added span is a big deal for you, you can fiddle with css settings like this:

```
.heading { 
  line-height:0.1em;
  height: 0;
} 

.heading.active::before {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: Thanx, the first answer was exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that purely via css

```
.heading:hover { 
   text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

Comment: They want it to go across the entire page.